# SSH.NET How to decompress on-the-fly

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I have an image of 2Gb `image.gz`. Right now I am doing the following steps to get the decompressed `image.gz` on the target machine:

1. Upload `image.gz` using `Renci.SshNet.ScpClient`.
2. Decompress the file by running remote `Renci.SshNet.SshCommand`.

These 2 steps take around 4 minutes to complete and I want to speed up this process.

If I could use a simple command line, I would just write the following command:
`cat image.gz | ssh 10.70.0.1 "gunzip -C - > /var/tmp/decompressed_image"`

This command completes in 2 minutes, which is twice as fast as before.

---

I have attempted to implement this one-liner with Renci.SSH:

```
  sshClient.Connect();

  var shellStream = sshClient.CreateShellStream(
      terminalName: "dumb",
      columns: 80,
      rows: 24,
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      bufferSize: 1024);

  while (!shellStream.CanWrite)
  {
      Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  }

  shellStream.WriteLine("cat - | gunzip -c > /var/tmp/image.raw");
  shellStream.Flush();

  long totalBytes = 0;
  const int bufferSize = 1024;
  using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\images\image.gz"))
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize))
  {
      var buffer = new byte[1024];
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = streamReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
          totalBytes += bytesRead;

          if (totalBytes % Megabyte == 0)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(totalBytes / Megabyte);
          }

          while (!shellStream.CanWrite)
          {
              Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
          }

          shellStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
   }
```

As you've guessed it, this code doesn't work. This was my only idea of how this could be implemented.

If you have better ideas (working ideas :) ), please share them with me.

Comment: Your code seems fine (sans any typos or off-by-one I could miss by jsut reading it), what's the effect? Are there any errors reported from unzip?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Thank you for your suggestions. This is a small console app which I made to test whether I could do what I've described. The effect is that this loop ends pretty fast and there is an empty file created on the target machine. I also looked at the list of processes (`ps aux`) and found neither `cat` nor `gunzip`.

Comment: re `while (!shellStream.CanWrite)` strangeness - [Renci.SshNet/ShellStream.cs](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/ShellStream.cs):  `public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return true; }
        }` :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Write has the following signature: `void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`